# How to edit Edit Profile And View Profile page (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, user-profile, user-management

I have created web-application using Joomla 2.5.

In that I have used Joomla user management. I have kept menu as View Profile & Edit Profile (Menu Item Type as Users Manager » User Profile). The problem is when I click on View Profile, I get un-wanted data also as shown below.

```
Basic Settings

Editor: Editor - JCE
Time zone: No Information Entered
Frontend language: No Information Entered
Backend Template Style: No Information Entered
Backend language: No Information Entered
Help Site: No Information Entered
```

so what I want is edit this page and show only what I wanted. Any idea what steps I need to follow to edit the same?

### Edit 1

After following Lodder answer I am able to remove Basic settings. Now on page I have

```
Profile

Name:: dummy name
Username:: id
Registered Date: Sunday, 07 October 2012
Last visited date: Tuesday, 09 October 2012
```

However what I want is

```
Profile

Name:: dummy name
Username:: id
Email Id :: dummy@dummy.com
Phone :: 12345678
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these simple steps:

1. Go to the Joomla backend
2. Go to User Manager
3. Open the Paramaters window
4. Set "Frontend User Parameters" to "Hide"

**Update:**

To replace the last 2 fields with e-mail and phone, I firstly recommend you do a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) so that you are not editing any core Joomla files.
What you want to be overriding is the following:

```
root/components/com_users/views/profile/tmpl/default_core.php
```

Once you have overridden this file, open it and starting on line 31, you will see the following code:

```
<dt>
    <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_PROFILE_REGISTERED_DATE_LABEL'); ?>
</dt>
<dd>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('date', $this->data->registerDate); ?>
</dd>
```

which needs to be replaced with:

```
<dt>
    <?php echo "E-mail"; ?> 
    //or you can make this language based. Up to you.
</dt>
<dd>
    <?php $user = JFactory::getUser();
          echo $user->email; ?>
</dd>
```

The same applies for the other field which I assume will be something along the lines of this, depending on how you created it:

```
<dt>
     <?php echo "Phone"; ?> 
     //or you can make this language based. Up to you.
</dt>
<dd>
     <?php $user = JFactory::getUser();
           echo $user->phone; ?>
</dd>
```

Comment: I have seen your edit. Where are you getting the field "phone" from?

Comment: I have created additional field using "Plug-in Manager: User - Profile"

Comment: I made changes, but nothing is happening

Comment: try doing it without the template override, therefore just try editing components/com_users/views/profile/tmpl/default_core.php

Comment: still same problem.... I believe if I change this file, it will be effective at two places. View Profile & Edit profile page both... right??

Comment: no, I didn't take "edit profile" into account. This was only to show you how to view other fields on the "view profile" page as requested. make sure you are changing the right file. I tested this yesterday when writing the answer and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I played with "templates/temp_name/warp/systems/joomla/layouts/com_users/profile" folder....