# Creating profile page for users in Joomla

Tags: joomla, authentication, user-profile

I have been developing websites for some years. I know PHP. but I have never worked with a CMS before. I've been told to create a website with Joomla where there's a homepage and also new users may sign up and then they can have a profile page where they can upload their profile picture and write their résumé.
This is easy for me to implement this system if I start coding it by myself. but how can I do this in Joomla? is there a plug-in which I need? could someone please give me some resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to re-invent the wheel - there are tons of ready-built components at the [Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities).  Last I checked Community Builder and JomSocial were the most popular, but they might be overkill for your need, so it's worth having a look at the other choices there.  If you're new to Joomla, you're probably interested in a Component, which is essentially a "sub-application" that installs under Joomla.  They usually include Modules that can be displayed on the site, as well as Plugins that work with the core Joomla logic to perform specialized functions for the installed component.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins, but the simple functionality of user profiles is implemented in Joomla. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808024/how-to-edit-edit-profile-and-view-profile-page-joomla-2-5) might help you.